# Flutter Freezed Expected to find ')'

Tags: flutter, freezed

After upgrading my Flutter, Freezed appears to generate files that have errors in them for my Bloc/Cubit files.

Pubspec.yaml has all the latest versions for the packages.

```
part of 'test_cubit.dart';

@freezed
abstract class TestState with _$TestState {
  const factory TestState.initial() = _Initial;
  const factory TestState.loaded(String someValue) = _Loaded;
}
```

Would be generated as (only excerpt where error occurs)

```
/// @nodoc
class _$TestStateTearOff {
  const _$TestStateTearOff();

_Initial initial() {
  return const  _Initial();
}
_Loaded loaded( String* someValue) {
  return  _Loaded(someValue,);
}

}
```

Image of the errors

[image]

When I delete the * it all works just fine.  Can anyone shed some light on this please?

Comment: Submit an issue on their Github page.

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL Is it an issue or is it something that I am doing wrong somewhere?

Comment: you are doing the right thing, but `Freezed` does not seem to be doing it right.

Comment: Have you updated freezed packages and build runner as well in pubspec?

Comment: The latest freezed package recommends we don't need abstract classes.
https://github.com/rrousselGit/freezed/tree/master/packages/freezed#the-abstract-keyword
Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: @rkdupr0n  No, that makes no difference.  I will put the answer below - forgot about this question in all the madness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered on [GitHub](https://github.com/rrousselGit/freezed/issues/411) in the end.
The issue was identified after running a check to ensure the the application was fully migrated to null-safety.

```
$ dart pub upgrade --null-safety
null-safety compatible versions do not exist for:
 - build_runner
```

When running `flutter pub run build_runner build` it yielded an error

```
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies don't support null safety:

 - package:build_runner_core
 - package:build_runner
 - package:build_config
 - package:build_daemon
 - package:code_builder
```

After editing the `pubspec.yaml` and setting a higher environment it worked.  This was not automatically done as part of the upgrade (or new applications).

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0"
```

Comment: Ahh... Weird. I never had to run that command. I just changed my sdk version and it worked for me.

Comment: @rkdupr0n I missed updating my SDK in the yaml file (I presumed it was changed as part of the upgrade) and those commands pointed at what was causing the issue.